# How to animate NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

I need to animate the color and scale of an attributed string. `CATextLayer` does not work for me, because it can only change the foreground color for plain strings..

I found another solution, but I did not get it to work either  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715191/animating-nsmutableattributedstring-color-the-string-disappears)

I need to get it to work on both Mac and iOS.
I think layers would be ideal, because I can do the scaling there easily..

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to animate a property that is not animatable, you can use [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html). That allows you to create your own animation by executing a method every time the screen refreshes. Although it looks sort of low-level, it is not really difficult to implement it.
You can find tutorials/examples on the web easily.

Note: It does not trigger your method periodically, therefore do not assume anything about timing and keep a counter and calculate progress your animation by yourself. Apart from that, `CADisplayLink` is cool.

Edit: As Max pointed out, `CADisplayLink` is not available for Mac. But there is `CVDisplayLink`, I guess you can achieve the desired animation by that. For more info on `CVDisplayLink`, you can have a look at [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165842/1515075) by Brad Larson.

Comment: Unfortunately CADisplayLink is only available on iOS, not OS X

Comment: I found an equivalent of CADisplayLink in Mac SDK: CVDisplayLink